# Can I re-ask someone else's question from the forums here?

Tags: discussion, copyright

I found a [tumbleweed on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1430303) that I would like to know the answer to. Can I just copy-and-paste it into Ask Ubuntu and cite the original author with a link back to the forums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer appears to be yes!

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/

Comment: Nice find @Jorge Castro.